# C# call SOAP webservice from console application

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

This seems very trivial, but it is not working for me at all. I am attempting to call a `soap web service` from within my c# console application. The app is built for .net 4.5.  Here's what I did:

> - Added the service reference to the project in visual studio 2013 by pointing it to the wsdl. It finds the Service and it's operations fine.
> - Attempt to create an instance of that service by doing the following:

```
            ServiceReference1 s = new ServiceReference1();
```

I get the following error code:

```
Project1.ServiceReference1 is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'
```

Any ideas? I've searched for this for a while and can't come across someone having the same problem with a real solution. I will provide any more info needed.

Comment: if the class name is ServiceRefrence1 and you called the actual reference ServiceRefrence1 its ServiceReference1.ServiceReference1

Answer (score 2):

If you already added the service reference to the project you see the reference. In this case you left a default name 'ServiceReference1'.

Now you want to call the web service's methods, for this you have to instantiate a SOAPClient.

```
    ServiceReference1.YourWebserviceNameSoapClient client = new  ServiceReference1.YourWebserviceNameSoapClient();
    client.HelloWorld(); // call of webmethod
```

now you access the webmethods under the 'client' object.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a service reference, Visual Studio 2013 will generate a proxy class you can use to transparently call into the service. The default proxy namespace is `your_project_name.ServiceReference1`. The type is the name of your service.

For an example service `http://localhost/YourService.svc`.
You generate the Service Reference `ServiceReference1` from your console project `ConsoleApp`. The generated files have the namespace `ConsoleApp.ServiceReference1`. The type is `YourService`.

```
var service = new ServiceReference1.YourService();
```

will return an instance of the proxy generated by Visual Studio. Then you will be able to call any of the service methods.

Comment: Okay that appears to be my issue. I don't exactly know the service name (in your example, YourService). Intellisense also is not suggesting it. Do you know if the proxy class will somewhere contain the needed information?

Comment: You should be able to put the cursor over the namespace and hit F12 (Go to definition). If that doesn't work, `<project file directory>\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs` should have the proxy class definition.